# SudsLibrary Robot Framework : incorrect WSDL parsing

Tags: web-services, soap, robotframework, suds

It seems that my request SOAP object is being parsed incorrectly by SudsLibrary 0.8. Given that I have the following complex type:

```
<complexType name="getSchoolRequest">
    <sequence>
        <element name="school_name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="school_type" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="requestee" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="requestee_age" type="xsd:int"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
<element name="getSchoolRequest" type="impl:getSchoolRequest"/>
```

I generate the SOAP message with the following code:

```
Check SOAP Service Functional
    create soap client  ${WSDL_ENDPOINT}

    ${mySchoolRequest}=  create wsdl object  getSchoolRequest
    ${mySchoolResponse}=  call soap method  getSchoolResponse  ${mySchoolRequest}
```

As a result, I get this SOAP message as the final creation:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://jaxws.webservices.my.srv/schemas" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:getSchoolRequest>
         <ns0:school_name>
            <ns0:school_name/>
            <ns0:requestee/>
         </ns0:school_name>
         <ns0:requestee/>
      </ns0:getSchoolRequest>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What I expect to see instead is something like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://jaxws.webservices.my.srv/schemas" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:getSchoolRequest>
        <ns0:school_name/>
        <ns0:school_type/>
        <ns0:requestee/>
        <ns0:requestee_age/>
      </ns0:getSchoolRequest>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

SoapUI confirms that the version I expect is the one that generates. Am I missing something with SudsLibrary in making this generation accurate?